# why the results come with two title for the table in sql?

Tags: sql, oracle

A simple example for this which I want to list all the information in one table with some condition. And I used `select * from employee where dno=5;`

The data indeed is found and presented as below.
[image: example]

but I have concern about the title column FNAME, M, LNAME...why it is shown twice in the result?

Comment: could be something from the front-end.. limited display?

Comment: I don' t think so because I tried another queries it got split as well.

Comment: that's odd behaviour.. don't see any reason why it should display like that.

Comment: the only thing the comes to mind are limited display or paging.

Comment: Looks like a display setting for pagination

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is sqlplus because of the Oracle tag, the header prints at the top of every "page" based on the sqlplus settings.  Use `set pagesize n` where `n` is a high number, e.g., `set pagesize 50000`.  See the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch6.htm#i1082471).